# Sort by month in linq and EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a linq query and inside of it is the month name. I want the results sorted by the month (Jan, Feb, Mar, ...).

Currently I have the below but it's giving me and error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime
>   Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression.

```
var shockValues = (from s in ctx.Shocks
                               where s.ID == id
                               orderby DateTime.Parse(s.MonthName)
                               select new 
                               {
                                   val = s.MonthName + "=" + s.ShockValue
                               });
```

Comment: why not `orderby s.MonthName`

Comment: if `MonthName` is a `string` you'll need to do something like `order by s.MonthName == "Jan" ? 1 : s.MonthName == "Feb" ? 2 : ...`.

Comment: Because it's a string and won't order by the months correctly

Comment: Oh man, no better way :(

Comment: @user441521 Not if you want to do the ordering in the DB.  Even in raw SQL I think you'd have to do something with `CASE` to get it to work.

Comment: To parse by datetime, you need date and year part too

Comment: Do you actually want to order by MonthName as opposed to Month?

Comment: By Month. I was trying to convey that when I said "I want the results sorted by the month (Jan, Feb, Mar, ...)."

Comment: You could create a table in your DB that maps the Month Name to a ordinal number, then join to that table in your query and use that to order by.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got few options.  You could use a long list of optional operators to map the names to numbers

```
order by s.MonthName == "Jan" ? 1 : s.MonthName == "Feb" ? 2 : ...
```

You could create a table in your DB that maps the names to nummeric values

```
var shockValues = (from s in ctx.Shocks
                   join o in MonthOrder on s.MonthName equals o.MonthName
                   where s.ID == id
                   orderby o.MonthNumber
                   select new 
                   {
                       val = s.MonthName + "=" + s.ShockValue
                   });
```

Or do the ordering in memory

```
var shockValues = (from s in ctx.Shocks
                   where s.ID == id
                   select new
                          {
                              s.MonthName,
                              s.ShockValue
                          })
                  .AsEnumerable()
                  .OrderBy(s => DateTime.ParseExact(s.MonthName, "MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Month)
                  .Select(s => new 
                               {
                                   val = s.MonthName + "=" + s.ShockValue
                               });
```

Comment: The in memory one is great. Thx!

Comment: @user441521 that is only a good idea when you do not expect lots of Shocks

Comment: @esskar Well the filtering is still done in the DB.  I guess it would be a little better to only select the required columns though.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
var shockValues = ctx.Shocks.Where(s => s.ID == id).Select(x => new {x.MonthName, MonthNum = x.MonthName == "Jan" : 1 ? x.MonthName == "Feb" : 2 ? 0}).OrderBy(s => MonthNum).Select(s => new {val = s.MonthName + "=" + s.ShockValue}
```

Comment: The alphabetical order of month names is not the same as their order as they occur within the year.

Comment: Because MonthName is "Jan", "Feb", etc this won't order correctly because it's a string.

Comment: `DateTime.Parse` isn't going to work with EF.  That's the issue the OP is having in the first place.

Comment: I get the idea. I guess I could do the if in my select to get the number and then select on that.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
orderby Convert.ToDateTime(s.MonthName + " 1, " + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString()).Month
```

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: You did use "Convert.ToDatetTime" as opposed to "System.DateTime.ToDatetTime", correct?

Comment: This is via EF so you can't use any of those functions directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to create a table in your database, you can do like

```
var names = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.MonthNames
            .Take(12).Select(s => new[] {s.Substring(0,3)});
```

And then order against a separate list.

```
orderby names.IndexOf(s.MonthName)
```

Comment: @juharr But names list is not an EF list its a normal string array.

Comment: EF still has to translate that to SQL

Comment: Juharr then probably has the right approach. Once you cast it to AsEnumerable then you should be able to use Cnvert and the other DateTime functions.

Answer (score 0):

The best way and easiest way is create a stored procedure

```
Create procedure sortevents
   as
 SELECT *
        FROM [SAGMJ].[dbo].[Events]
        ORDER BY CASE 
                 WHEN MONTH([StartAt]) = MONTH(GETDATE())
                    AND YEAR([StartAt])  = YEAR(GETDATE()) THEN 0
                   ELSE 1
                 END, [StartAt];
```

//Next call your sp

```
var v = (dc.sortevents()).ToList();
```